# EPERM, operation not permitted error, config store

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-7, permissions

I know this is a common error with `node` but all my troubleshooting techniques seem to be failing.

- Windows 7 (32-bit)
- Node@0.10.10
- npm@1.2.25

This issue occurs when trying to run package commands like `bower` and `yo` (Yeoman). For my sanity, I am in a Node.js command prompt running as an Administrator when executing these commands.

For example, here is the output for running this with `yo`:

```
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Users\me\.config\configstore\insight-yo.yml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
    at Object.create.all.set (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\insight\node_modules\configstore\configstore.js:39:7)
    at Object.Configstore (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\insight\node_modules\configstore\configstore.js:30:11)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\insight\lib\insight.js:20:16)
    at Object.<anonymous (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\bin\yo:25:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Essentially, it seems the `node` process can't write to this `.config` folder.

I've tried the following to troubleshoot:

- Fresh installs of `node` and the individual packages (in every conceivable order)
- Setting write privileges for all users on the `.config` folder
- Reinstalling `git` after reading the notes for Windows users in the npm repository

Any thoughts or troubleshooting techniques on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

I solved the problem by just deleting the file at `C:\Users\<your username>\.config\configstore\insight-bower.yml`, bower will recreate it upon running.

Comment: Worked for me deleting `bower-github.yml`

Comment: It's the same thing if it's a `.json` instead of `.yml`... delete that sucker

Comment: I had the same issue with my `cordova-config.json` file after I upgraded my global/project/platform level cordova libraries. Deleting the offending file works!

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me to delete the .yml file inside the configstore which was causing the problem. In my case it was "update-notifier-bower.yml", in yours it is probably "insight-yo.yml".

After a reinstallation of bower (npm -g install bower) the file reappeared, but this time it caused no harm.

It has also been [reported](https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs/issues/19) that the deactivation of the anti-virus software solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me there were three files
at C:\Users\myusername\.config\configstore

(bower-github.yml, insight-bower.json, update-notifier-bower.yml) delted all three

Also disabled the antivirus.

Note: Don't forget to show hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

Just change windows rights for "all users" onto the "configstore" directory and bower will correctly install the package

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running Yeoman generators on Windows. McAfee real-time scanning was preventing file system changes. Setting the real-time scanning to "Programs and documents only" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me navigating to the file with the File Explorer caused a pop up to appear which granted me permission to access the file.

After that `nodemon` ran without problems.

Answer (score 0):

running `npm cache clean --force` helped me.
`npm cache clean` by itself with node 5+ gives this warning:

> npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

[NPM cache documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache).

Note: my real problem was the package-lock.json file. I had done some things locally and thought they were removed, but got to the build agent and got this error. It would probably help to delete the node_modules folder and do a fresh `npm install`.