# Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron

I am working with Electron, trying to create a simple example app to view a local sqlite database file. I'm using sql.js and just using their example for connecting to a local database file, but I keep running into issues. My app works just fine on mac, but when I try to run the exe on windows, I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write

I have an index.html, main.js, and app.js files. The main.js file opens the index.html file and the html file runs functions specific to the db in the app.js file.

I am using virtualbox running windows 7 for my testing environment for windows. I'm not sure if I'm even headed in the right direction with this approach. I'm using node v5.0.0, npm v3.3.9, electron v0.34.0, and sql.js v0.2.21.

Any feedback including alternatives would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to avoid localstorage and indexeddb for specific personal reasons. Also, this is my first question to ask, so I apologize if I leave something out.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the response I got from a quick google search did not work for me, then I remembered I just turned on Controlled Folder Access in Ransomware Protection in Windows Security, turning it off fixed it for me

Comment: I was trying to flash on a sdd for home assistant and this helped me out big time.

Thank you very much. How would we live without stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common bug in Node applications. 
Using Windows Explorer try navigating to

`%USERPROFILE%\.config\configstore`

and deleting all the `.yml` files like "bower-github.yml" As they are usually autogenerated when you run the app. Take a backup of the "configstore" folder in case you are unsure of deleting them.

Source:
[EPERM, operation not permitted error, config store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989013/eperm-operation-not-permitted-error-config-store)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, you should try to re-install your app on a partition different of C: one, 
I tried it for my case and it worked !