# This npm install is not working on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

This works great in my Mac. But the same process on Windows and the npm install crashes. This is what I get.

I've tried everything I've seen on Stack Overflow so far and every link Google search produced. I tried the following as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401606/npm-doesnt-install-module-dependencies):

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

It didn't work.

I:

- ran it as admin,
- tried npm install -g
- restarted the [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) server
- turned off [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender)
- checked the PATH for *C:\Program Files\nodejs*

#### Output

```
warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
warn fuse@1.4.4 No description
verbose If you need help, you may report this error at:
verbose     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
warn fuse@1.4.4 No repository field.
verbose If you need help, you may report this error at:
verbose     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
warn fuse@1.4.4 No license field.
verbose If you need help, you may report this error at:
verbose     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\accessibility-developer-tools'
verbose stack     at destStatted (C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
verbose stack     at C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:276:29
verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
verbose stack
verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\accessibility-developer-tools'
verbose stack     at Error (native)
verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM
error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Luis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
error node v6.9.1
error npm  v4.0.2
error path C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290
error code EPERM
error errno -4048
error syscall rename
error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\accessibility-developer-tools'
error     at destStatted (C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
error     at C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:276:29
error     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
error
error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\accessibility-developer-tools'
error     at Error (native)
error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\accessibility-developer-tools'
error     at destStatted (C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
error     at C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:276:29
error     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
error
error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\accessibility-developer-tools-2e33f290' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\accessibility-developer-tools'
error     at Error (native) parent: 'fuse' }
error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

*node -v* gives me version 6.9.1.

*npm -v* gives me version 4.0.2.

Which proves they are all installed fine. Am I right?

Comment: kill any node processes you have running then try again

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After countless hours of debugging and researching, I decided to install on a different machine to see if the problem was with my Node.js installation. It worked.

Know that the possibility to uninstall Node.js and delete NPM will be there. This is what I did. I believe it is the safest way to solve the problem and all the rest of your applications installed in your machine will still work.

I credit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) for these steps, although I had other npm and [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) in other locations. So do a quick search for these and unless they are part of an application, make sure they are deleted as well.

1. Uninstall from *Programs & Features* with the uninstaller.
2. Reboot (or you probably can get away with killing all Node.js related processes from [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows))).
3. Look for these folders and remove them (and their contents) if any still exist. Depending on the version you installed, [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) settings, and CPU architecture, these may or may not exist:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs`
- `C:\Program Files\Nodejs`
- `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm` (or `%appdata%\npm`)
- `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` (or `%appdata%\npm-cache`)
- `C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc` (and possibly check for that without the `.` prefix too)

4. [Check your `%PATH%` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344/how-to-check-if-directory-exists-in-path) to ensure no references to Node.js or npm exist.
5. If it's *still* not uninstalled, type `where node` at the command prompt and you'll see where it resides -- delete that (and probably the parent directory) too.
6. Reboot, for good measure.

Comment: This is the true answer. The gotcha here for me was to delete .npmrc from %APPDATA%. I tried everything before without success (even uninstalling).

Comment: to check environment variables use the commandline and just type `SET`

Comment: Definitely still the only option I've found that works. Has worked on three separate installations.

Comment: You can't 'fix' npm if it breaks (as described here). These instructions on how to nuke the site from orbit are the only way to be sure.

Comment: This is perfect answer. You really saved my day I had already spent 4 days in this issue tried many solutions but this is full detailed answer that really help me out. Cheers !

Comment: Umm, how is this any kind of answer? It just removes all traces of Node. The Op's npm install command is *definitely* not going to work if NodeJS is not installed.

Answer (score 5):

Please read the error carefully.

It's saying:

```
fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}
```

> The FSEvents API in OS X allows applications to register for notifications of changes to a given directory tree.

It needs OS X, because some of the npm dependencies are using [fsevents](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents). That's why it’s breaking on Windows.

As you were told, it's working without fsevents. Then you can follow these steps:

Install [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) and try again.

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u       # It will update the npm dependencies.
rm -fr node_modules
npm install
```

It will update the dependencies and install the dependencies.

Comment: oh, ok, I see now. SO how do I change it so that it is cross-OS? I inherited this from another developer who quit. I can't just ask him where he put this or how he did it. Any idea of where I should look or how to change it globally?

Comment: I ran the application in a mac after uninstalling fsevents and it still runs in t a mac. So I'm safe not having it. But I can't figure out how to remove it or stop it from blocking a WIndows install

Comment: Hi Please check the updated answer. Hope It will help :)

Comment: It did't work. Same error. But it says it is optional so I ran $npm install --no-optional and that error went away but I still can't install. I am getting this npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Luis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-optional"

Comment: And also this    npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\.staging\acorn-4ac2b9e1' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ScalaCM\node_modules\acorn'

Comment: Try this:
npm cache clean

Comment: if still not work :   %APPDATA%\npm-cache 

check these links 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows 

2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt-harrington/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems/

Comment: nothing. and the last one is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132845/discussion-between-vishnu-mishra-and-lotusms).

Comment: You're a real life saver. NPM was hanging on NPM install and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please try to open the console as an administrator.

Do right-click on the command line and select "Open as administrator" and then try installing the dependency.

Comment: I did that. As I mentioned in my question

Comment: please check the permissions you have on your htdocs folder. OR stop your Xampp server and try installing.

Comment: refer these links : 1. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)                                                          2. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989013/eperm-operation-not-permitted-error-config-store)

Answer (score 3):

Update and then install again:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates

npm install
```

Add this to fix any errors:

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked for me was deleting npm and npm-cache from *C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming*.

And uninstalling Node.js and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

If npm install is not working, then you can use this command:

```
 npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This works for me.

Comment: worked for me. I have updated angular version 8 to 9. For the first time need to run this command. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Node.js and npm with nvm, then you can uninstall it with *nvm uninstall 5.5.5*, and then reinstall with *nvm install 5.5.5*.

That fixed my issue. I did not have to go in to delete or add modules or change paths.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to disabled all my antivirus and firewall, cleared the npm cache, and did cache verify, but nothing worked. The only thing that works on my end is to install the Node Version Manager, `nvm`.

How does **Node Version Manager** work?

Permission errors can occur when packages are installed globally. If this is the case, npm may need to be set up to operate without elevated permissions. This where nvm comes in. It lets you install a different Node.js version without triggering the administrative access.

1. If you have existing Node.js installed, I recommend uninstalling it like the process given by LOTUSMS above:

   > Uninstall from Programs & Features with the uninstaller.
   >
   > Reboot (or you probably can get away with killing all node-related
   > processes from Task Manager).
   >
   > Look for these folders and remove them (and their contents) if any
   > still exist. Depending on the version you installed, UAC settings, and
   > CPU architecture, these may or may not exist:
   >
   > C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs C:\Program Files\Nodejs
   >
   > C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
   >
   > C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
   >
   > C:\Users{User}.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the .
   > prefix too) Check your %PATH% environment variable to ensure no
   > references to Nodejs or npm exist.
   >
   > If it's still not uninstalled, type where node at the command prompt
   > and you'll see where it resides -- delete that (and probably the
   > parent directory) too.
2. Install nvm here - https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows.
   or you can use
   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`
3. Run `nvm` or `command -v nvm`. If something prints, the installation was successful.
4. Install the prefered node version - e.g. `nvm use 16.3.0`
5. Check if the node and npm are properly install. Just run `node -v` and `npm -v`
6. Enjoy the npm installation :D

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

npm install --force

Answer (score 0):

Is still does not work for you, try this:
Go to "C:\Windows\System32" folder and see if you do not have an empty file called “npm”.
We used to do this, in the old days in Unix, to prevent people from deleting files.