# cannot install nvm in ubuntu

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-16.04, nvm

i want to install nvm to my ubuntu, but i think there is network problem

to install nvm i use this code :

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

output error:

```
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

and it's always error in nineteen seconds,
btw i use windows subsystem for linux

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum, people can ask such questions. Previously have been asked.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570364/npm-install-not-working-in-windows

Comment: People can but they shouldn't. Just because someone else breaks the rules doesn't mean it is ok for anyone else to do the same. Please read the link given as that is the official Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: this is a programing question: installing nvm within with wsl.
@Abr did you end up figuring it out?