# NPM command is not working after clear the cash in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have uninstalled node.js from my windows 10. And installed the LTS version (14.7.5). Now ***npm install*** command is not working in my angular project. The following error shows:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install not working in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570364/npm-install-not-working-in-windows)

Comment: Solved the problem. package-lock.json file was missing.